# Lucene index byte[]

Tags: c#, lucene.net

In my application I read the system files in `byte[]` and index it using Lucene 2.9
below is the code

```
byte[] readByteContent = File.ReadAllBytes(@"G:\pass.txt");
doc.Add(new Field("FILECONTENT", readByteContent,0,
                  readByteContent.Length, Field.Store.YES));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

Now I want to search the index data, but as my data is indexed in `byte[]` what is the correct approach to create a query on `byte[]` data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary fields are not indexed, therefore you cannot issue queries on these fields.

The method you use to add the field will store it, but it's content is not indexed. It is meant to attach arbitrary binary data with the `Document`.

Comment: but lucene provide method for indexing binary data. Syntax: Field(String name, byte[] value, Field.Store store)
          Create a stored field with binary value.

Comment: its stored, but not indexed